A crash issue. The process dies for only rviz 2 when it gets started with ignition gazebo fortress and parameter bridge from a python launch file
It seems that this crash issue has nothing to do with whether the launch variables (rviz 2, ignition gazebo fortress & parameter bridge) are provided as executable processes or nodes. The crash issue happens in both cases a few seconds after rviz 2 has started. I've tried to separate the execution timings for the launch variables through timers but that doesn't help & the process still dies for only rviz 2. I'm sharing the bash terminal output & the python launch file code for reference.
bash terminal output -
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/assets/package-01/launch# ls
__pycache__  demo-01_sim.launch.py
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/assets/package-01/launch# ros2 launch demo-01_sim.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /root/.ros/log/2024-07-02-14-40-50-184170-LAPTOP-GL67113F-76
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [ign-1]: process started with pid [77]
[ign-1] QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
[ign-1] Service [] is not valid.
[ign-1] libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open vgem: /usr/lib/dri/vgem_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\\\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
[ign-1] 
[ign-1] libEGL warning: NEEDS EXTENSION: falling back to kms_swrast
[ign-1] libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open vgem: /usr/lib/dri/vgem_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\\\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
[ign-1] 
[ign-1] libEGL warning: NEEDS EXTENSION: falling back to kms_swrast
[INFO] [ros2-2]: process started with pid [397]
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920460.694760105] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/camera (gz.msgs.Image) -> /camera (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920460.705764562] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/camera (sensor_msgs/msg/Image) -> /camera (gz.msgs.Image)] (Lazy 0)
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920460.710179735] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/camera_info (gz.msgs.CameraInfo) -> /camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920460.711129761] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo) -> /camera_info (gz.msgs.CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920460.711944388] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/image (gz.msgs.Image) -> /rgbd_camera/image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920460.712352668] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image) -> /rgbd_camera/image (gz.msgs.Image)] (Lazy 0)
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920460.712738376] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/camera_info (gz.msgs.CameraInfo) -> /rgbd_camera/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920460.713112120] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo) -> /rgbd_camera/camera_info (gz.msgs.CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920460.713585335] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/depth_image (gz.msgs.Image) -> /rgbd_camera/depth_image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920460.713881631] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/depth_image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image) -> /rgbd_camera/depth_image (gz.msgs.Image)] (Lazy 0)
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920460.714285633] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/points (gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked) -> /rgbd_camera/points (sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2)] (Lazy 0)
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920460.714772905] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/points (sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2) -> /rgbd_camera/points (gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [rviz2-3]: process started with pid [415]
[rviz2-3] QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1719920470.640287548] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1719920470.640433116] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5)
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1719920470.763466953] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1719920471.483914222] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1719920471.681984175] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ERROR] [rviz2-3]: process has died [pid 415, exit code -11, cmd 'rviz2 -d /root/ws/assets/package-01/config/rs-general-igngz.rviz'].
[INFO] [ign-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 77]
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[ros2-2] [INFO] [1719920517.837424886] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[INFO] [ros2-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 397]
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/assets/package-01/launch#

python launch file code -
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess, IncludeLaunchDescription,  TimerAction
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    pkg_share = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    # Gazebo Ignition simulation world launch
    world_file = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'worlds', 'demo-01.sdf')
    ign_gz = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ign', 'gazebo', world_file],
        output='screen'
    )
    # ROS2-Gazebo Ignition parameter bridge launch
    bridge = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=[
            'ros2', 'run', 'ros_gz_bridge', 'parameter_bridge',
            '/camera@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image',
            '/camera_info@sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo@gz.msgs.CameraInfo',
            '/rgbd_camera/image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image',
            '/rgbd_camera/camera_info@sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo@gz.msgs.CameraInfo',
            '/rgbd_camera/depth_image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image',
            '/rgbd_camera/points@sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2@gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked'
        ],
        output='screen'
    )
    # RViz2 viewer launch
    rviz_config_file = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config', 'rs-general-igngz.rviz')
    rviz2 = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=[
                'rviz2',
                '-d', str(rviz_config_file)
            ],
        output='screen'
    )
    # Launch Description variables
    return LaunchDescription([
        ign_gz,
        TimerAction(period=10.0, actions=[bridge]), 
        TimerAction(period=20.0, actions=[rviz2]),  
    ])

edit note 1 -
There's no crash if i provide just any two of my three launch variables but there's a crash if i provide all three of them at once.
edit note 2 -
It seems that a pre-made ignition gazebo world file can't be provided as a ros 2 node variable, although new world files can be created as ros 2 node variables.

I've identified the issue. When i try starting rviz 2 with the "-d" option from a python launch file & when i try loading a configuration file after starting rviz 2 from a python launch file, it crashes (the process dies) specifically for the configuration file containing depth cloud & point cloud data display but is able to load a configuration file containing depth image & color image data displays. I tried including & excluding different data displays for the configuration file to check which one was responsible for the crashes. It seems to be the depth cloud data display in my case, although i don't know why. Excluding it specifically resolved the crashing issue for me but it's only a temporary solution.
